# Add Arrays of (parse.com) to a UICollectionView SubView

Tags: ios, parse-platform, subview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add a label (string array) from Parse.com into a subview that shows up after tapping an image inside a UICollectionViewCell.

The subview appears, and the text also but it's the same text in every subview of each cell. It is not changing..
The arrays in my dataBrowser are: precio_0, precio_1, precio_2 etc..

What am I doing wrong? How would the code go to recognize it is another cell. If I set the code in the UICollectionViewCell and not in the Subview there is no problem, the text changes in every view. So I'm missing something but don't know what it is.

**NOTE: This is the DetailView and the data is being passed as a property so to get the data the method goes: [self.vestimenta objectForKey:@"String"]

My code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoadLook.png"];

PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%ld", (long)indexPath.row]];

[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error && data.length > 0) {

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *infoLook = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

    infoLook.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [cell.imageFile addGestureRecognizer:infoLook];

} else {

    [cell.progressView removeFromSuperview];

        }

} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
    float percent = percentDone * 0.02;
    [cell.progressView setProgress:percent];
    if (percentDone == 100){
        [cell.progressView removeFromSuperview];
    };

    [cell.showInfo addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(handleTap:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}];

return cell;
}


-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) infoLook{

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 519);

UIView *infoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
infoView.opaque = NO;
infoView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8f];
infoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
infoView.tag = 01;

UIButton *priceTag = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(282, 370, 25, 25)];
[priceTag setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Price.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UILabel *precioProductos = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 370, 240, 190)];
precioProductos.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
precioProductos.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
precioProductos.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
precioProductos.numberOfLines = 0;
precioProductos.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-LightItalic" size:15];
```

This part shows the calling of the arrays in Parse.com:

```
VestimentaDetailCell *price = (VestimentaDetailCell *)[precioProductos superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [imagesCollection indexPathForCell:price];
NSMutableString *precio = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString* precios in [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"precios_%ld", (long)indexPath.row]]) {

[precio appendFormat:@"%@\n", precios];
    }

precioProductos.text = precio;
[precioProductos sizeToFit];
CGRect myFrame = precioProductos.frame;
myFrame = CGRectMake(myFrame.origin.x, myFrame.origin.y, 240, myFrame.size.height);
precioProductos.frame = myFrame;

[infoView addSubview:priceTag];
[infoView addSubview:precioProductos];

[self.view addSubview:infoView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *dismissView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processTap:)];

dismissView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[infoView addGestureRecognizer:dismissView];

}
```

Comment: I don't see any **PFQuery** being fired so how do you fetch data from parse as per which cell being clicked.

Comment: This is the Detail View. I've passed the data and the method to getting the data is: self.vestimenta....

Comment: your code not that clear to understand but I so far I could say that when a user tap on image then you should pass that indexpath to the array (like : `NSArray *resultArray = [self.vestimenta objectAtIndex:0];`) then you go for  `[resultArray objectForKey:YOUR_KEY]` on that particular object that you got.